# failed to send transaction: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account

Tags: anchor

I am trying to build a web3 based e-commerce site using Anchor.

I've just started learning about PDAs and there's a error I've been getting for hours, like the one in the title.

My contract:

```
#[program]
pub mod dailsap_store_contract {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_collection(
        ctx: Context<CreateCollection>,
        name: String,
        description: String,
        image_uri: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let collection: &mut Account<Collection> = &mut ctx.accounts.collection;
        let authority: &Signer = &ctx.accounts.authority;
        let clock: Clock = Clock::get().unwrap();
        let bump = *ctx.bumps.get("collection").unwrap();

        if name.chars().count() > 50 {
            return Err(ErrorCode::CollectionNameTooLong.into());
        }
        if description.chars().count() > 250 {
            return Err(ErrorCode::CollectionDescriptionTooLong.into());
        }
        if image_uri.chars().count() > 60 {
            return Err(ErrorCode::CollectionImageUrlTooLong.into());
        }

        collection.authority = *authority.key;
        collection.timestamp = clock.unix_timestamp;
        collection.name = name;
        collection.description = description;
        collection.image = image_uri;
        collection.bump = bump;

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn update_collection(
        ctx: Context<UpdateCollection>,
        name: String,
        description: String,
        image_uri: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let base_collection: &mut Account<Collection> = &mut ctx.accounts.collection_account;

        base_collection.name = name;
        base_collection.description = description;
        base_collection.image = image_uri;

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateCollection<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(init, payer=authority, space = Collection::LEN, seeds=[b"collection", collection.key().as_ref()], bump)]
    pub collection: Account<'info, Collection>,

    #[account(address = system_program::ID)]
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
#[account]
pub struct Collection {
    authority: Pubkey,
    timestamp: i64,
    name: String,
    description: String,
    image: String,
    bump: u8,
}
```

Frontend:

```
  const collection = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

    const [collectionPDA, _] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [
        anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("collection"),
        collection.publicKey.toBuffer(),
      ],
      program.programId
    );

    await program.methods
      .createCollection(
        "This is collection name",
        "This is collection description",
        "Hello World"
      )
      .accounts({
        collection: collectionPDA,
        authority: anchor.AnchorProvider.env().publicKey,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      })
      .rpc();
```

The problem should be here: `seeds=[b"collection", collection.key().as_ref()]`

The source from which I received help: https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_in_depth/PDAs.html

But I'm getting errors in a way I don't understand

can you help?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the on-chain PDA derivation all wrong. The public key being derived cannot have itself as one of its seeds(afterall it hasn't been derived and so you don't know it yet). Here you're deriving `collection` with one of its seeds being `collection`. That is unacceptable.

An appropriate way to create a PDA for a collection is:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateCollection<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    authority: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(init, payer=authority, space = Collection::LEN, seeds=[b"collection".as_ref(), authority.key().as_ref()], bump)]
    pub collection: Account<'info, Collection>,

    ..
}
```

And in your client code derive the PDA like this:

```
const [collectionPDA, _] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
   [
     Buffer.from(anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("collection")),
     authority.publicKey.toBuffer(),
   ],
   program.programId
 );
```

This way you get a unique collection account for each user(authority).

Comment: `seeds=[b"collection".as_ref()...`  i updated it, I get the same error.

Comment: I tried, but the error persists :(
I think this is the wrong approach, because i couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying for a while and I realized that I can't solve it this way.

So I came up with a solution like this, I'm not sure how logical it is.

```
...
#[program]
pub mod dailsap_store_contract {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_collection(
        ctx: Context<CreateCollection>,
        id: Pubkey,
        name: String,
        description: String,
        image_uri: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let collection: &mut Account<Collection> = &mut ctx.accounts.collection;
        let authority: &Signer = &ctx.accounts.authority;
        let clock: Clock = Clock::get().unwrap();
        let bump = *ctx.bumps.get("collection").unwrap();

        if name.chars().count() > 50 {
            return Err(ErrorCode::CollectionNameTooLong.into());
        }
...

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(id: Pubkey)]
pub struct CreateCollection<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(init, payer=authority, space = Collection::LEN, seeds=[b"collection", id.as_ref()], bump)]
    pub collection: Account<'info, Collection>,

    #[account(address = system_program::ID)]
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Collection {
    id: Pubkey,
    authority: Pubkey,
    timestamp: i64,
    name: String,
    description: String,
    image: String,
    bump: u8,
}
...
```

Frontend:

```
 const collection = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

    const [collectionPDA, _] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [
        Buffer.from(anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("collection")),
        collection.publicKey.toBuffer(),
      ],
      program.programId
    );

    await program.methods
      .createCollection(
        collection.publicKey,
        "This is collection name",
        "This is collection description",
        "Hello World"
      )
      .accounts({
        collection: collectionPDA,
        authority: anchor.AnchorProvider.env().publicKey,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      })
      .rpc();
```